# find: only delete files which we're allowed to delete

Tags: permissions, find

I'm using `find` to delete files matching some criteria:

```
find -type f [more criteria] -delete
```

That works fine, in general, but I'm running into issues with sub-directories created by other users: as far as I understand, whether I'm allowed to delete a file [depends on my permissions w.r.t. the parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622747/857390). Hence the command above fails for files contained in a sub-directory created by another user:

```
fbrucker@host /tmp $ ls -lh
total 4,0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4,0K Jun 15 11:44 foo/

fbrucker@host /tmp $ ls -lh foo/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fbrucker fbrucker 0 Jun 15 11:44 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     root     0 Jun 15 11:44 b

fbrucker@host /tmp $ find -type f -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./foo/b’: Permission denied
find: cannot delete ‘./foo/a’: Permission denied
```

It's OK that I cannot delete the files, but the missing permissions make `find` exit with a non-zero status. I'd like to avoid that.

**How can I filter out files that I cannot delete before trying to delete them?**

Note that simply filtering out the error messages is *not* enough for me, since that will still leave me with the non-zero exit code. Also, ignoring the exit code completely won't work for me, because I do want catch other errors (my real `find` command is more complex, for example for `find /somedir -type f -delete` I'd like to *not* ignore the error that is raised when `/somedir` does not exist).

I know that `find` has tests for the file's permissions (e.g. `-perm`, `-readable`, `-writable`), but I don't think they apply here. For example,

```
fbrucker@host /tmp $ find -type f -writable
./foo/a
```

even though I cannot delete `foo/a` since I don't have the necessary permissions on `foo`.

What I'm looking for is something like a `-deletable` test, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: In general, the problem with stuff like `-deletable` is the classic "time of check to time of use" issue. The permissions of a file might change in the middle, so that `-deletable` would be truthy, and the deletion would still fail. It's better to just try to do it and deal with or ignore the error later.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to have write access to the parent directory and if that directory has the `t` bit set, be either the owner of that directory or of the file you want to unlink, and all that assuming other security controls like ACLs are not in place and that the FS the file is on is not read-only which makes the *is deletable* check more complicated.

For `-readable` / `-writable` / `-executable` (non-standard) `find` can just use the corresponding `access(R_OK/W_OK/X_OK)` system call, but there's no equivalent for *unlinking* a file.

With GNU `find` 4.9.0 or newer, you can do an approximation with:

```
find . -depth -type d -writable '(' -uid "$EUID" -o ! -perm -o=t ')' -print0 |
  find -files0-from - -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

(also assuming a shell like `zsh` or `bash` that sets `$EUID`. If not, use `"$(id -u)"`).

That leaves the files you own in `t`-bit directories you don't own which you'd need to handle separately:

```
find . -depth -type d -writable ! -uid "$EUID" -perm -o=t -print0 |
  find -files0-from - -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -uid "$EUID" -delete
```

You'd likely want to set the `pipefail` shell option as well to be able to detect errors by the first `find`.

With older versions of GNU `find`, you can always do:

```
find . -depth -type d -writable '(' -uid "$EUID" -o ! -perm -o=t ')' -exec sh -c '
  exec find "$@" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
  ' sh {} +
```

If the point is to ignore failures to unlink files as long as it's because of access rights, you could do:

```
set -o pipefail
find . -depth -type f -print0 |
  perl -l -0ne '
    unless (unlink($_) || $!{EACCES}) {
      warn "$_: $!\n";
      $ret = 1;
    }
    END {exit $ret}'
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use `-exec rm {} \;` instead of `-delete`, since `find` ignores the exit code of the `-exec` calls.

Comment: Strictly speaking, It doesn't ignore it. The exit code determines whether the predicate succeeds. So you can do `find . -exec rm -f {} \; -printf '"%p" was successfully deleted.\n'` for instance.

Comment: You'd likely want to use the `-f` option of `rm` unless you're happy for it to be interactive.

Comment: if you used `-exec ... {} +`, it would actually ignore the exit code of the executed command. (but you should still use `rm -f`)